# How to iterate ManyToMany filed in serializer class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have this Event model:

```
# models.py

class Event(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200))
    user = models.ManyToManyField(User))
```

This is my ListCreateAPIView class:

```
class EventListView(LoginRequiredMixin, generic.ListView):
    model = Event
```

This is my ListCreateAPIView class:

```
class Events(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated,)
    queryset = Event.objects.all()
    serializer_class = EventSerializer
```

This is my serialiser class:

```
#serializers,py
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        fields = (
            ‘id',
            'name', 
            'user',
        )
        model = Event
```

And this is my REST request response:

```
{
    "count": 2,
    "next": null,
    "previous": null,
    "results": [
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name": "My event1",
            "user": [
                1,
                4
            ],
            "registered": true             // <—- I NEED THIS 
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name": "Other event",
            "user": [
                2,
                4,
                6
            ],
            "registered": false             // <—- I NEED THIS 
        }
    ]
}
```

What I am gonna need in REST response is property “registered”, which will contain true or false if current user is registered on particular event or not.
My approach was to control if current user is in list of users of event. I tried to get this information in serialiser class this way:

```
#serializers,py
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    registered = serializers.SerializerMethodField(‘_user’)

    def _user(self, obj):
       request = getattr(self.context, 'request', None)
       if request.user in self.user:
           return True
       else:
           return False


    class Meta:
        fields = (
            ‘id',
            'name', 
            'user',
        )
        model = Event
```

But I get `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'user'`

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try like this using [`exists()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.exists) with `filter` method:

```
class EventSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    registered = serializers.SerializerMethodField(‘_user’)

    def _user(self, obj):
       request = self.context.get('request', None)
       if request and obj.user.filter(pk=request.user.pk).exists():
           return True
       else:
           return False
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but it always gives me False value.

Comment: If I print `print('obj.user', obj.user)` in `def _user(self, obj)` function I get `obj.user auth.User.None`

Comment: Are you using generic list view? https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/generic-views/

Answer (score 0):

In view.py add
For This "registered": true             // <—- I NEED THIS

```
model_name.object.filter(column='required value')
```